# In logic app , pass only 1 email attachment to Form Recognizer API

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-form-recognizer

Im trying to analyse the 1 attachment per email, using Logic App and Forn Recognmizer API but it's creating a "For Each Loop" as it could be more than 1 attachment per email.  How can I limit to 1 and ditch the loop ?

Thanks
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an expression to set a variable (or the like) to single out the attachment.

This is the expression I used to set a variable of type `Object` ...

```
first(triggerOutputs()?['body/attachments'])
```

This is the result ...

[image: Result]

... that will avoid looping.  You'll just need to do the work to get the relevant property value (likely `contentBytes`) into the form recognizer operation.